# Update the have list of a client to reflect what's in the HD

Tags: perforce

I have this situation: I have many files on my HD that come from an old perforce server. The new server has the same files, but the "have list" is not up to date, and according to it I have no files.
The server is not 100% like my HD, so if I run "p4 flush" I'll break it, because many files that are not in my HD but are in the server will be marked as "have" and will not be synced later.

Is there a way to sync the have list exactly to what you have in your client?

Thanks very much for you help!
Alex

Answer (score 1):

Start with a `p4 flush` to your best guess, and then do `p4 clean` to force-sync everything that doesn't match.

Comment: This sounds like a possibility: let me have a go :)